# How to predefine a message and send it in Slack chat?

Tags: slack

Let's say I have a message which I constantly send, `"Can you please update the status of the project?"`. Is there a way to save this message somewhere and send it using a Slash command like  `/proj-status` . Or is there any other way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I use small workflows like this. To use it I hit the shortcut icon in the #support channel then "Please open a ticket" and it posts that boilerplate message "Click on the question mark etc etc". It's handy if you're repeating yourself a lot, but also if you want to spend time once writing a careful reply and reuse it.

[image: slack workflow builder]